# Restrict the overlap between the events in fullcalender

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar.js for adding the events on particular date and time.

Everything is working fine. And i can add more than one event in particular time. If i am adding more than one event means, events are getting overlap each other. Like below image.

[image: events with overlap]

But, I want to restrict the overlap between the events in day view and week view. Like below.

[image: Events without overlap]

I tried below things,

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(
                                    {
                                        defaultView : 'agendaDay',
                                        header : {
                                            left : 'prev,next today',
                                            center : 'title',
                                            right : 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                                        },
                                        buttonText : {
                                            today : 'Today',
                                            month : 'Month',
                                            week : 'Week',
                                            day : 'Day'
                                        },
                                        views : {
                                            week : {
                                                // options apply to basicWeek and agendaWeek views
                                                titleFormat : 'MMMM DD, YYYY'
                                            },
                                            day : {
                                                // options apply to basicDay and agendaDay views
                                                titleFormat : 'DD MMMM YYYY'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        selectable : false,
                                        defaultDate : todayDate,
                                        editable : true,
                                        eventOverlap : false
});
```

Added the **eventOverlap** properties, but it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use below configuration to you calendar to avoid event overlap

```
slotEventOverlap: false
```

This works for me.